Compression results from EZW paper not reproducible?
I have been doing some research into the Embedded zerotrees of wavelets algorithm as a reference method for a journal. I found a couple of implementations of it in Matlab, python, and C and was able to run a few of them on the gray Lena test image as well as the gray Mandrill image. The PSNR vs CR curves from all of them varied and the best methods were still off from the source by a compression rate factor of ~5x. I decided to implement it myself in Matlab, following the paper and Wikipedia example to a T. After running mine I got a small improvement but still drastically more bytes per DB than the 1993 Shapiro paper. I looked for other journals that reference it but have not found one that runs the test images, preferring to just copy Shapiro's results. The only thing I have differently is that the encoder I use is Huffman and not the "adaptive arithmetic encoding". I will attach my qualitative and quantitative results here, any suggestions would be appreciated.
Paper: https://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid862310.pdf
Wiki: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_zerotrees_of_wavelet_transforms
For these tests, I ran EZW for 5 levels of decomposition with Huffman encoding. I also tested "wcompress" function for ezw and got better results but still worse than the paper.


Link to the paper? Depending on the statistics of the data, arithmetic coding can indeed be a huge gain over Huffman. You may be able to approximate arithmetic with Huffman by coding multiple symbols into a single code. By the way, PSNR is a terrible measure of image quality. I can take an image and add very low-level noise to every pixel, giving a huge PSNR, but you won't be able to tell which image is which.

Paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/258085
Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_zerotrees_of_wavelet_transforms
PSNR is one of the metrics they used and is very common in image compression. Of course it has plenty of flaws but as far as I know there isn't one widely accepted metric

Also, here I used matlab's "hummanenco" with a fixed dictionary suggested by other projects. I tried matlab's huffmandict function and "arithenco" but both were more bits.

You need to put the link in the question.

Yes, PSNR is very commonly used. Not because it is useful, but rather because it is easy to calculate. Keep in mind that not everything that can be measured matters, and not everything that matters can be measured.

Here's a copy that's not behind a paywall.

Thanks, I added the links to the question, I am fairly certain its the Huffman that causes the issue but the paper doesn't give much insight into what they used. I can also attach a link to my source code.

Sorry for potentially naive comment/questions. 1) What's the entropy like of the encoder input/output and does it match your expectation? 2) Section IV.C of the paper suggests that the alphabet of the entropy code is at most size 4. That would make adaptability relatively cheap, and if the probabilities change significantly as you progress (as would seem to be the case), it would be beneficial (and the paper seems to suggest so). With such small alphabet, coding multiple symbols together as Mark suggests would be the way to go if you want to use Huffman coding. (e.g. combos of 4)

Do you mean the entropy of my Huffman encoder? The alphabet is a size of 4, I used a fixed dictionary with Huffman of dict = {[1],[ 0];[2],[ 1 0]; [3],[ 1 1 0]; [4],[ 1 1 1 0]}; I did some tests in zipping the final bitstream and it did provide some reduction in size but not enough to suggest the encoding is not doing its job. Most of the size reduction is most likely a part of the subordinate pass bits being repetitive.

I just tried using matlab's "wcompress" function, it gets better results but still noticeably worse than the paper
